# In Java why cant we use an inner class with name as String if the parent class has psvm

Tags: java

```
public class OuterClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello !");
    }

    private class String {
      int i = 10;
    }
}
```

The above code compiles fine

When I tried to run the above code, it is throwing error as  " Error: Main method not found in class , please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)" . Any reason why such a Runtime Exeption occurs ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because your inner class has higher visibility than `java.lang.String`; thus you have changed the `main` signature. Change your `main` like

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello !");
}
```

Or rename your class `String`.